# Changing widget's style attribute via qproperties

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

Is it possible change one particular attribute in style sheet without calling setStyleSheet again? Some easy cases I solved by using attribute selectors (similar to CSS) and custom properties that define "type" or "state" of widget.

Let say I need to change border width in run-time.For that I should change attribute "border", and I have defined a custom property borderWidth of type int. CSS does support pseudofunction attr() that could used to compute value of one attribute from another. Apparently it doesn't work with Qt style sheet, e.g.

```
QTablo [state="3"] {
     border: attr(qproperty-borderWidth);
}
```

after unpolish();polish();update(); routine I see no no changes. Is there a workaround for this other than to set style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Qt only supports a subset of CSS2, attr() seems to be first mentioned in CSS2.1.

You could:

- Use a `QFrame` and change its properties, instead of using a style sheet.
- Generate the stylesheet at run time and assign it. Something like `QString("border-width: %1px;").arg(borderWidth);`.
- Use a custom `QProxyStyle` that returns the correct value in `pixelMetric()`.

Comment: change of qframe properties is not compatible with style sheets, they overrule it. Second bullet is what happening now, it is a costy opertion becase every time a new qstyle object is created. Do you have any references to the last method?

Comment: Other than the official documentation, no. Maybe start with [Creating a Custom Style](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#creating-a-custom-style) and [Using a Custom Style](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#using-a-custom-style). The short version is: Derive a class from QProxyStyle, override pixelMetric(), use the style. It is actually not complicated.